# I can't change background color tabs on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs, background-color

I have this code:

```
ttk.Style().configure("TNotebook", background="#1976D2",
                      tabmargins=[2, 5, 2, 0])
ttk.Style().map("TNotebook.Tab", background=[("background", "red")],
                foreground=[("selected", "#FFFFFF")])
ttk.Style().configure("TNotebook.Tab", alternate="red", background="red",
                      foreground="#757575", padding=[10, 10])

#######################

#################### NOTEBOOK
tabs_notebook = ttk.Notebook(root, width=300, height=300, takefocus="True")

##################### TAB 1
tabs_notebook.add(guards_tab, text='Guardias')  

####################### TAB 2
services_tab = ttk.Frame(tabs_notebook)
tabs_notebook.add(services_tab, text='Servicios')

# label.pack(side="top")
tabs_notebook.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'New Window', width = 25,
                         command = self.new_window)
self.button1.pack()
colored_btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Test", style="C.TButton").pack()
self.frame.pack()`
```

I have defined style on ttk, but it is not working. Tabs don't change but I have no idea why. Then.. Why is not working this? and What can I do instead of?

Comment: The 'code of tabs' is missing a line.  But only one tab is needed to illustrate the problem.  Please merge two code block, remove what is not needed, add what is needed, and  post instead an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.